# TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.haderHomepage.animateIntro') on Macos Big sur

Tags: javascript, typescript

and the details of the error after that:

```
onPreloaderDone - app.js:57191:93
onComplete app.js:57176
anonymous function - app.js:441
anonymous function - app.js:32994
anonymous function - app.js:614:209
anonymous function - app:js:837
anonymous function - app:js:254
g app.js:277
```

while the same page works fine in chrome, firefox on windows.
I am trying to add the relevant line of the app.js file if it makes any sense.
line 57145 - 57214

```
new class {
        constructor(t) {
            var e = $$("#preloader")
              , i = t.lottie.loadAnimation({
                name: e,
                container: e,
                renderer: "svg",
                loop: !1,
                autoplay: !1,
                path:  "themes/sailor/js/preloader.json"
            });
            i.addEventListener("data_ready", (r=>{
                t.lottie.play(e),
                TweenMax.to($$("#preloader"), .1, {
                    css: {
                        opacity: "0"
                    },
                    onComplete: ()=>{
                        $$("body").classList.add("loaded"),
                        this.headerHomepage = t.monoPages.headerHomepage,
                        t.monoReveals.startObserve(!1),
                        t.monoReveals.initLinesReveals(),
                        t.monoRevealsWords.startObserve(!1),
                        TweenMax.fromTo($$("#transition"), 1.2, {
                            scaleY: 1,
                            transformOrigin: "50% 100%",
                            backgroundColor: "#434A7F"
                        }, {
                            scaleY: 0,
                            backgroundColor: "#191919",
                            onComplete: ()=>{
                                this.onPreloaderDone(),
                                i.destroy()
                            }
                            ,
                            ease: Expo.easeOut
                        })
                    }
                    ,
                    delay: 2.6,
                    ease: Expo.ease
                })
            }
            ))
        }
        onPreloaderDone() { //next line below is 57191
            "home" == $$(".mono-container").getAttribute("data-page") ? this.headerHomepage.animateIntro() : (TweenMax.to(".menu.menu--main", .6, { 
                opacity: 1,
                y: 0,
                ease: Power2.easeOut
            }),
            TweenMax.to(".top.top--main", .6, {
                opacity: 1,
                y: 0,
                ease: Power2.easeOut,
                onComplete: ()=>{
                    $$("body").classList.add("preloader-done")
                }
            }))
        }
    }
    ({
        lottie: uh,
        monoReveals: dh,
        monoRevealsWords: fh,
        gravThemeUrl: ch,
        monoPages: yh
    })
}
]);
```

so while I tried to check for any 404 error or anything else missing, but couldn't find any.
looks like it is a mac specific issue and need some change in the code for it to work on safari macos big sur.

Note: I also observed that in the body tag class "preloader done" is not added. whereas in windows machine where it is working okay this class is being added fine.